# Publish Off-Chain Item with On-Chain "notes" in multichain?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info-api

I was reading the "publish" description in the JSON-RPC API and I had a doubt about the possibility of my application. I needed to publish an off-chain item with some metadata information embedded on-chain.  For example: "iPhone 2018, New, $400" on the blockchain while {picture.jpg} goes off-chain,

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to publish two stream items simultaneously in a single transaction – one off-chain and one on-chain. You can have the both in the same stream, or in two different streams. These two items will be naturally associated with each other since they will have the same transaction ID. See the **publishmulti** API (in MultiChain 2.0) for making this easy.